# Button DataTrigger not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

Please help...

Why does this work..

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="btnDefaultStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0"  To="-5" BeginTime="0:0:0:5.00" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="-5" To="0"  BeginTime="0:0:0:5.05" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="0" BeginTime="0:0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But this not...?

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="btnDefaultStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0"  To="-5" BeginTime="0:0:0:5.00" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="-5" To="0"  BeginTime="0:0:0:5.05" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="0" BeginTime="0:0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I really need my trigger to bind using a DataTrigger as I will eventually be creating a MultiDataTrigger that has 2 conditions. One of them being the IsEnabled property on the Button and the other being a property on my View Model.

The code above is in my App.xaml file.

Thanks.

Comment: What's different about them? We don't know instantly what something is supposed to do, and what isn't working about it!

Comment: Isn't `{RelativeSource Self}` in that case the `DataTrigger` or the `Style` and NOT the `Button` the style is applied to?

Comment: Hi @David, the top one uses a Property trigger and the bottom one uses a DataTrigger. The top one works but the bottom not. From everything I have researched you can use a DataTrigger to access a property. But this is not the case here.

Comment: Hi @Adwaenyth. Maybe it is. I don't know of any way of checking. From all the examples I have seen, this is how a DataTrigger refers to its target type.

Comment: Is the Button you want to assign this style to data bound? Because if you do not reference a source WPF will try to find the `Property` on the `DataContext` if no source is specified. In that case, I'd give your view model object a `DependencyProperty IsEnabled` and just bind the button and the `Style` to that.

Comment: All my buttons are bound using Command bindings.

Comment: Any relevant results when diagnosing the binding with `xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"` and `Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"` ?

Comment: Sorry @grek40, xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=Window‌​sBase" does not exist in my project and I can neither find it in Assemblies or NuGet. :(

Comment: WindowBase should be available in project "References - Assemblies - Framework - WindowBase". Ofc. the `xmlns` declaration belongs to the top element of the xaml file, but I guess that's not your problem.

Comment: @grek40. got it. I'll have a go. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @grek40, I tried all variations of the namespace for diag: xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase", xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=mscorlib" & xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics.Tracing;assembly=mscorlib". Non of them show valid syntax on my binding. The diag: alias is not available. All I wanted to do was switch off the button wobble animation if a global view model property was false. I guess it's just not that simple. Thank you for you input.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's not as obvious as I thought. the `xmlns:diag` declaration __is the namespace alias__ and belongs to the same place at top of file, where all other namespaces are defined (like `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`). Then the `diag` will be ready for use in the binding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129542/discussion-between-ian-gm-and-grek40).

Comment: Change this `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}` to `{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}`

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you. I'll try it next week. Working on another project just now.

Comment: @ChrisW. Still no good. I get this compiler error when trying TemplateBinding... 'IsEnabled' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice that there is no ControlTemplate within your Style, that would throw that error expectedly. Fair enough, I'll circle back when I get a chance to load up VS and try some thing.

Comment: @ChrisW. In my full style (example above trimmed for brevity) does have a ControlTemplate within my Property=Template Setter. I also have a ControlTempate.Trigger that sets various properties when IsEnabled=False. I really have lost the will to live with this. Even VS crashes when I try different things for this. So I think I'm actually going to give up with NOT POSSIBLE for now. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Oh I know it's possible, I've done it, just haven't been working in xaml as much lately.